# How to perform a query in an included array of objects in Sequelize using nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables.

- `Users` table, storing my user information.
- `Expertises` table, storing fields of expertises.
  (e.g: `Construction', 'Programming', etc..)

Each user has a unique id and each expertise also has a unique id.

every user in my table may have several 'Expertises'.
There's a many-to-many table connecting the users and their expertises called `UsersExpertises`.

In the `UsersExpertises` table I am storing the `userId` and `expertiseId`, and when I want to fetch all expertises of a specific user I can simply query by his id and get his expertises. I am using Sequelize `include` for that.

Everything I just explained works amazing up until now. My issue:

I need to add a search feature to my app, so our users can search other users, my search algorithm is searching in several columns in the users table and also, one of the search parameters should include their expertises.. So, if someone types 'Programming', which is a name of an expertise, I need to return a list of all users that has that expertise.

So, the `where` query that I have so far:

```
const where = {
        [Op.and]: [
            // Only search for active user profiles.
            { isActive: true },
            // Make sure we filter our searching user from the results
            { id: { [Op.ne]: userId } }
        ],
        [Op.or]: [

            // Search user by their first and last names
            { firstName: { [Op.substring]: keyword } },
            { lastName: { [Op.substring]: keyword } },
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
                [Op.substring]: keyword
            }),

            // Search business name and description.
            { businessName: { [Op.substring]: keyword } },
            { businessDescription: { [Op.substring]: keyword } },

            // Search in expertises and cities.
            // { '$expertises.name$': { [Op.substring]: keyword } }, // TODO - This doesn't work.
            { '$city.name$': { [Op.substring]: keyword } }
        ]
    };
```

And this is the final output (if it matters):

```
{
    "id": 35,
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Hasslehoff",
    "city": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Los Angeles"
    },
    "expertises": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Construction"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Programming"
        }
    ]
}
```

Take a look at this line:
`{ '$city.name$': { [Op.substring]: keyword } }`

`City` is an object I am including in the `User` table in this query, this works perfectly since `City` is an object that can be attached to a user with only one city, but a `User` may have multiple `Expertise`, so the included `Expertise`s is an array of `Expertise` objects.

How can I have search for a 'name' of 'Expertise' inside my included array? Can this be done?

I hope I have included all the needed information for you all to understand my issue, if there's something missing, please let me know and I'll provide you with whatever is needed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can try `sequelize.literal` because in your scenario you don't need Expertise records for each found user.

Comment: @Anatoly could you please provide a code example?

Comment: something like sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`exists (select true from UsersExpertises join Extertises on (UsersExpertises.extertise_id=Extertises.id) where Extertises.name like '%${keyword}%'`), true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving input on `Sequelize.literal` from @Anatoly in the comments, I have managed to work my way towards my solution.

Thanks Anatoly.

In case someone else have a similiar issue in the future, I'm attaching my code:

```
            {
                [Op.or]: Sequelize.literal(`EXISTS(
                    SELECT EF.id, EF.name FROM UsersExpertises AS UE
                    JOIN ExpertiseFields AS EF
                    ON EF.id = UE.expertiseId
                    WHERE UE.userId = User.id
                    AND EF.name LIKE '%${keyword}%')`)
            }
```